# Pressing Enter on a date input in Cypress

Tags: date, cypress

I have an app with some input fields that I'm trying to automate. The gist of these fields is that I should be able to double click a field, type in a new value, then press Enter to submit that value, which sends a PUT request and also closes the input field. This works for any input type except date.

So far I've tried:

- Using `cy.type('{enter}')`. This gives `Typing into a date input with cy.type() requires a valid date in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd'. You passed: {enter}`
- Using `cy.trigger()` to send out a keydown event for the enter key. This works, as in it closes the input field successfully but it somehow doesn't send the PUT request.
- Pressing enter on the parent Element. Same as using `cy.trigger()`

Strangely enough, manually opening the input field myself, typing a date and pressing enter will send the request just fine. It seems to me like there's some issue with programmatically pressing enter to submit the field without Cypress interpreting this as my attempt to actually type an invalid character into the date field. The docs do specifically say that no special characters are allowed in a date field.

Can't post any code as this is corporate.

Answer (score 23):

I have tried to let it work, but it simply can't be done at the moment. Something like this should work:

```js
it.only('test', function () {
    cy.visit('https://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-date.php')
    cy.get('input')
      .type('2009-12-12')
      .type('{enter}')
  })
```

But it doesn't so I started to dig into the pile of issues and found this one:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3405 . It is about a different input type, but I believe it is related to your problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer but now in the updated cypress you can just write `cy.get('input').type('2009-12-12{enter}'`

Comment: or `cy.get('input').type('2009-12-12'); cy.get('input').type('{enter}');`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this problem is still present in Cypress 9.5.  One possible work-around is to directly trigger the Javascript keyup or keydown event that you are listening for.

```js
cy.get('input')
  .type('2020-01-01T12:00')
  .trigger('keydown', {
    key: 'Enter',
  });
```

This works for me, but as you pointed out might not in all situations.  It depends entirely on how your app is listening for Enter in the first place and on which element.

Another possible option is to call `.submit()` on the form that wraps the input.  If you're testing a component, you could create your own wrapper component that contains a form in order to trigger the submit.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove 'date' attribute like below:

```
 cy.get('input').invoke('removeAttr','type').type('2009-12-12{enter}');
```

Comment: imagine writing code

Answer (score 0):

I used something like that in my code, and it worked properly

```
cy.get('get-your-input').invoke('removeAttr', 'type')type('2022-12-01{enter}').trigger('change');

cy.get('get-your-input').invoke('attr', 'value', '2022-12-01').trigger('change');

cy.get('get-your-input').invoke('attr', 'type', 'date');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add date plus enter keystroke in the type:  cy.get("#date").type("02-02-2022{enter}");